# How to convert JavaScript function doPostBack to HTTP arguments

Tags: javascript, jmeter, dopostback

How do i handle the Jmeter Post for the Java function below?

```
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument)
            var theform = document.Form1; 
            theform.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget; 
            theform.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument; 
            theform.submit(); `
```

The Jmeter Post does not update the database when I just pass the values eventtarget and eventargument like this:

```
{
    "__EVENTTARGET": "${_urlencode(ctl$ContentPlaceHolder1$btSubmit)}",
    "__EVENTARGUMENT": ,`
```

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint on the page load event and see what's being posted?

Comment: WHen i see the post this looks good. Not sure why it is still not posting. Below is the results i see       the below.                                 JMeterThread.last_sample_ok FALSE
tbPassowrd A!
Insurancenumber 91233
EVENTVALIDATIONExtractor lOlV4O36V8H6BflHqZVceEOwvRDVuHu81iarXRs4qHI6Sfj4fe6upCdCpDIzm4XkDQ8sVrJNvTnsNrgZEAz8gj9BBPVX8YO4emLwSrjM0Ug5TyanCOOKIE_Cookie_SessionExpire fygn5dnslfnpu03msfmxjozu
tbUsername Test1
JMeterThread.pack org.apache.jmeter.threads.SamplePackage@16f1a73

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to call __doPostBack, instead of just triggering the form submit event?

Comment: Just triggering the form Submit is not working. So wondering if i have to call_dopostback

Comment: No you don't.  Submit will trigger the __doPostBack function without you having to consider the event information.  Why are you also trying to set that?

Comment: Jmeter post with The click of submit button doesnot work .So wondering if i have to trigger it manually in jmeter.

Comment: No.  Something else is wrong in that case.  Do you have an event handler for the submit button?  If so, put a breakpoint in there and figure out what's going wrong.